# Open file, read it, process, and write back - shortest method in Python

Tags: python, coding-style

I want to do some basic filtering on a file. Read it, do processing, write it back.

I'm not looking for "golfing", but want the simplest and most elegant method to achieve this. I came up with:

```
from __future__ import with_statement

filename = "..." # or sys.argv...

with open(filename) as f:
    new_txt = # ...some translation of f.read() 

open(filename, 'w').write(new_txt)
```

The `with` statement makes things shorter since I don't have to explicitly open and close the file.

Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Actually an easier way using fileinput is to use the inplace parameter:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input (filenameToProcess, inplace=1):
    process (line)
```

If you use the inplace parameter it will redirect stdout to your file, so that if you do a print it will write back to your file.

This example adds line numbers to your file:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input ("b.txt",inplace=1):
    print "%d: %s" % (fileinput.lineno(),line),
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks for pointing this option out. You can also use the filelineno() function from fileinput to automatically have the line number, without counting it yourself.

Comment: Oh, and you forgot the comma after the print - the code adds extra newlines :-)

Comment: Thanks for catching that -- I have changed the example.

Answer (score 4):

I would go for elegance a different way:  implement your file-reading and filtering operations as generators,  You'll write more lines of code, but it will be more flexible, maintainable, and performant code.

See David M. Beazley's [Generator Tricks for Systems Programmers](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/), which is a really important thing for anyone who's writing this kind of code to read.

Comment: Excellent link -- thank you! I am a little concerned with the increased difficulty in debugging pipelines, but the power is undeniable.

Comment: Test-driven development is your friend.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work:

```
with open(filename, "r+") as f:
    new_txt = process(f.read())
    f.truncate(0)
    f.write(new_txt)
```

Comment: Works here only when calling `f.seek(0)` after `f.truncate(0)`, otherwise the new file starts with 11 zero bytes (Python 2.7.3 on Linux).

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the python equivalent of "perl -pi", here's a pretty good one:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
   # process line
```

See http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-fileinput.html for more.

Done this way, you would use your python script in a pipe to create the new file:

```
$ myscript.py infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

Comment: It doesn't really help me though, since I want to write back to the same file. And redirection won't work this way for the same file

Answer (score 1):

To do it in a way which won't [eat your data](http://www.linux.org.au/conf/2007/talk/278.html) if you crash in the middle:

```
from twisted.python.filepath import FilePath
p = FilePath(filename)
p.setContent(process(p.getContent()))
```

Answer (score 0):

My ugly (but short as stated in the question) solution with [generator expressions](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/ref/genexpr.html);

```
# Some setup first
file('test.txt', 'w').write('\n'.join('%05d' % i for i in range(100)))


# This is the filter function
def f(i):
    return i % 3


# This is the main part 
file('test2.txt', 'w').write('\n'.join(str(f(int(l))) for l in file('test.txt', 'r').readlines()))


# And a wrapper for sanity
def filter_file(infile, outfile, filter_function)
    outfile.write('\n'.join(filter_function(l) for l in infile.readlines()))
```